# How to set up workspaces with Chrome & WordPress?

Tags: css, workflow, sass

I'm using SASS & Gulp for my development.

Though I can’t properly setup workspace in Google Chrome.
I add project folder (should be theme folder, right?) but what should I map to what to edit SASS directly?

Gulp Task for styles is:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src(styleSRC)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sassPartialsImported('assets/css/'))
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true,
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(styleDestination))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(styleDestination))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream()) // Reloads style.css if that is enqueued.
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss({
            maxLineLen: 10
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(styleDestination))
        .pipe(filter('**/*.css')) // Filtering stream to only css files
        .pipe(browserSync.stream()); // Reloads style.min.css if that is enqueued.
});
```

Then I enqueue style.min.css to WordPress.

Comment: I recently found [UnderStrap](https://github.com/holger1411/understrap), a project combining _s and Bootstrap using gulp with browser sync for development. Not an answer, so I only comment, but their code may provide help

Comment: Thanks. Though gulp setup works fine, question is more about how to set that in Chrome. I'll edit the title.

Comment: Actually I had no idea what Chrome workspaces were .. Guess with browsersync and large enough screen to support multiple windows never had a need for that. Are you sure this is a WordPress question? From the text, it sounds like you're trying to figure out how to get workspaces and sass to play nicely together